# onAccuryChange always has 3 as value

Tags: android

I am trying to Learn How to detect shaking and tried to make App Detect Shaking
but onAccuryChange always on 3

```
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    switch(i){
        case 2:
            txt.setText("Shaked");
            break;
        case 3:
            txt.setText("Default");
            break;
        default:
            txt.setText("Nothing");
            break;
    }
}
```

always show "Default"
*The TextView Already Have Text="No Actions Yet"*

The mobile on Table but it shows "Default" once it run

so why it only gives 3 and how can i make it detect shaking ?

this is the Declaration

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer=sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);


}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Comment: did you tried changing switch numbers ? like starting with 0 ?

Comment: @ArmandoBarreda yes and it still show case 3 only

Comment: how case 2 knows when the device is shaking ? because its not a function or something that tells to that case that is shaking

Comment: I read that 1 mean low accury ,2 means medium, 3 means high and the value from 2nd parameter from OnAccuryChange

Comment: if you liked my code. Please up vote it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Follow with below steps:**

**Create interface with name "AccelerometerListener":**

```
 public interface AccelerometerListener {

public void onAccelerationChanged(float x, float y, float z);

public void onShake(float force);

}
```

Create Class name as "MainAccelerometer.java", it is main activity:

```
 public class MainAccelerometer extends Activity implements AccelerometerListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accelerometer_example_main);

    // Check onResume Method to start accelerometer listener
}

public void onAccelerationChanged(float x, float y, float z) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onShake(float force) {

    // Do your stuff here

    // Called when Motion Detected
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Motion detected", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onResume Accelerometer Started", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Check device supported Accelerometer senssor or not
        if (AccelerometerManager.isSupported(this)) {

            //Start Accelerometer Listening
            AccelerometerManager.startListening(this);
        }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        //Check device supported Accelerometer senssor or not
        if (AccelerometerManager.isListening()) {

            //Start Accelerometer Listening
            AccelerometerManager.stopListening();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onStop Accelerometer Stoped", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("Sensor", "Service  distroy");

    //Check device supported Accelerometer senssor or not
    if (AccelerometerManager.isListening()) {

        //Start Accelerometer Listening
        AccelerometerManager.stopListening();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDestroy Accelerometer Stoped", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

 }
```

**Create Class name as "AccelerometerManager.java", which act as manager for managing accelerometer.**

```
 public class AccelerometerManager {

private static Context aContext=null;


/** Accuracy configuration */
private static float threshold  = 15.0f; 
private static int interval     = 200;

private static Sensor sensor;
private static SensorManager sensorManager;
// you could use an OrientationListener array instead
// if you plans to use more than one listener
private static AccelerometerListener listener;

/** indicates whether or not Accelerometer Sensor is supported */
private static Boolean supported;
/** indicates whether or not Accelerometer Sensor is running */
private static boolean running = false;

/**
 * Returns true if the manager is listening to orientation changes
 */
public static boolean isListening() {
    return running;
}

/**
 * Unregisters listeners
 */
public static void stopListening() {
    running = false;
    try {
        if (sensorManager != null && sensorEventListener != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

/**
 * Returns true if at least one Accelerometer sensor is available
 */
public static boolean isSupported(Context context) {
    aContext = context;
    if (supported == null) {
        if (aContext != null) {


            sensorManager = (SensorManager) aContext.
                    getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

            // Get all sensors in device
            List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(
                    Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

            supported = new Boolean(sensors.size() > 0);



        } else {
            supported = Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }
    return supported;
}

/**
 * Configure the listener for shaking
 * @param threshold
 *             minimum acceleration variation for considering shaking
 * @param interval
 *             minimum interval between to shake events
 */
public static void configure(int threshold, int interval) {
    AccelerometerManager.threshold = threshold;
    AccelerometerManager.interval = interval;
}

/**
 * Registers a listener and start listening
 * @param accelerometerListener
 *             callback for accelerometer events
 */
public static void startListening( AccelerometerListener accelerometerListener ) 
{

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) aContext.
            getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    // Take all sensors in device
    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    if (sensors.size() > 0) {

        sensor = sensors.get(0);

        // Register Accelerometer Listener
        running = sensorManager.registerListener(
                sensorEventListener, sensor, 
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        listener = accelerometerListener;
    }


}

/**
 * Configures threshold and interval
 * And registers a listener and start listening
 * @param accelerometerListener
 *             callback for accelerometer events
 * @param threshold
 *             minimum acceleration variation for considering shaking
 * @param interval
 *             minimum interval between to shake events
 */
public static void startListening(
        AccelerometerListener accelerometerListener, 
        int threshold, int interval) {
    configure(threshold, interval);
    startListening(accelerometerListener);
}

/**
 * The listener that listen to events from the accelerometer listener
 */
private static SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = 
    new SensorEventListener() {

    private long now = 0;
    private long timeDiff = 0;
    private long lastUpdate = 0;
    private long lastShake = 0;

    private float x = 0;
    private float y = 0;
    private float z = 0;
    private float lastX = 0;
    private float lastY = 0;
    private float lastZ = 0;
    private float force = 0;

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // use the event timestamp as reference
        // so the manager precision won't depends 
        // on the AccelerometerListener implementation
        // processing time
        now = event.timestamp;

        x = event.values[0];
        y = event.values[1];
        z = event.values[2];

        // if not interesting in shake events
        // just remove the whole if then else block
        if (lastUpdate == 0) {
            lastUpdate = now;
            lastShake = now;
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            lastZ = z;
            Toast.makeText(aContext,"No Motion detected", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            timeDiff = now - lastUpdate;

            if (timeDiff > 0) { 

                /*force = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ) 
                            / timeDiff;*/
                force = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ);

                if (Float.compare(force, threshold) >0 ) {
                    //Toast.makeText(Accelerometer.getContext(), 
                    //(now-lastShake)+"  >= "+interval, 1000).show();

                    if (now - lastShake >= interval) { 

                        // trigger shake event
                        listener.onShake(force);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(aContext,"No Motion detected", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    lastShake = now;
                }
                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
                lastZ = z;
                lastUpdate = now; 
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(aContext,"No Motion detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
        // trigger change event
        listener.onAccelerationChanged(x, y, z);
    }

};

 }
```

**In Manifest, do a entry:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**Create layout file name as "accelerometer_example_main.xml":**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="<a class="vglnk" href="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>schemas</span><span>.</span><span>android</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>apk</span><span>/</span><span>res</span><span>/</span><span>android</span></a>"
xmlns:tools="<a class="vglnk" href="http://schemas.android.com/tools" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>schemas</span><span>.</span><span>android</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>tools</span></a>"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainAccelerometer" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Shake / Tilt Your Phone To Get Accelerometer Motion Alerts" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: i have less thatn 15 reputation so it doesnt Count , sry